# Correct Permissions to Manage Bulk API Jobs

Tags: api, bulk

One of my users ran an import of leads into the system. When the import was complete she received this e-mail notification:

*Your Leads import is complete. Here are your results:
Leads Created: 89
Leads Updated: 500
Leads Failed:  294 (We couldn't import these due to errors.) 
Processed job information for imported Leads: **No link is available because you do not have the correct permissions to manage Bulk Api jobs**.*

Can someone tell me what permission is required for her to receive the link to view the failed leads?

Answer (score 2):

Found it! The permission needed for this is the "Manage Data Integrations" on the user's profile.